# Fetch Text From Sqlite and show image too from drawable folder

Tags: android, sqlite

I create some apps when i fetch all of my data in listview name and text, and i want to display image too from drawable folder, but my problem is :
how to identify text 'name' from SQLite and Exactly images from drawable?
and if there no avaliable image with the same 'name' it must be blank.png from drawable images too, and i want it when i click some listview it would go to next activity to see detail text and describe from listview
[Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PbyHf.png)

- the left one is all list fetch from SQLite (import sqlite im using sqliteman)
- the right one is when im click 1 of the list and it show details
- all string from SQLite and all images from drawable folder

Comment: What you do so far ?

Comment: so far i can fetch all string from sqlite, im following this http://www.javahelps.com/2015/04/import-and-use-external-database-in.html , but its only fetch all string, and i want when the name=xx it will show image from drawable in listview , and i want when im click some listview it wouldbe onclicklistener and move into another activity

Comment: @MPG thanks for ask, already post above

Comment: u can save R.drawable.black as int in database and retrieve and set ImageVIEW.setImageResource() to set it

Comment: @ankitagrawal thanks for answer, how to save it in sqlite? can you give me an example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

for showing image from your Drawable Folder ->

```
ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.image_name);
```

And the listview item click to move another Activity ->

```
listView.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        Intent intent = new Intent(Context,ToActivoty.class);
        intent.putExtra("key",value); // If you want to pass any data to next activity
        startActivity(intent);
    }
});
```

Comment: yes i know how to showing image, but how to identify the name of list id with the exactly images?

Comment: You can make a HashMap by key value of the image key. 
like this ->

`HashMap<String,Integer> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
        hashMap.put("name1",R.drawable.image1);
        hashMap.put("name2",R.drawable.image2);
        hashMap.put("name3",R.drawable.image3);
        hashMap.put("name4",R.drawable.image4);`

next find the Resource id by the key value .

Comment: hmmm i thinks its not effiecient bc i have hundred images, how about just using if else? if(name=xx) then call image with the same name, how about with it?

Comment: Then keep the image name in your database . And get it from drawable folder . 

You can get the resId by this 

`int drawableResourceId = this.getResources().getIdentifier("imageName", "drawable", this.getPackageName());`

Comment: how to save images name in database? using insert like @ZAhidul provide?

Comment: Same way you put the name in your database . Just add an extra column to store image name .

Comment: aahhhh im not connect with that lol, so just store images name right? with int or blob type?

Comment: Type can be String / Text

Comment: then ill use text thanks :D, ill try implement, maybe ill ask again when i have problem or stuck :)

Answer (score 0):

First you have make a arraylist of all text and sort the text in Alphabetic order and in same manner you have to add Drawable resource id to another arraylist 
then For every index of text you have to fetch name of resource and match them with text.

```
getResources().getResourceEntryName(int resid);
```

or

```
getResources().getResourceName(int resid);
```

and if match set image and if not match then you can use blank image.

Comment: if im using the link im provide above, how to do that for showing images? can you help me?

Comment: @Raj From the matched index you can fetch image resource ID from arraylist and set to your imageview.

Answer (score 0):

when you are creating a `Table` use integer instead of text for drawable field and use insert and get as normal just use int instead of string

```
public long insertDrawable(String listviewId,int drawable) 
{
    ContentValues initialValues = new ContentValues();
    initialValues.put("id", listviewId);
    initialValues.put("drawable_res", drawable);
    return db.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null, initialValues);
}
```

where id and drawable_res is field name of table and id is string and drawable_res in Integer and you can use this to insert integer into database table

Comment: can you give me example?

Comment: Thanks, ill try implement first :)

Comment: hmm sorry, im already has database with name list.db im create using SQLiteman so how to save images name ? this link im following http://www.javahelps.com/2015/04/import-and-use-external-database-in.html